# calculation of input and out put resistance of OP AMP 741

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

The non-inverting amplifier shown in the following circuit uses a 741 Op-Amp with
R1=1K,R2=39K,R3=1K. The typical parameter values for the 741 Op-Amp are: Open loop
gain \$A_v = 2 × 10^5\$, Input resistance Ri=2M and Output resistance Ro=75ohm . What will be the Input resistance
and Output resistance for the non-inverting amplifier?
      [image]

Comment: You might be intrested in this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521

Comment: Do you know about the effects of negative feedback?

Answer (score 0):

For output resistance to be controlled, the circuit needs 1/G*H to be greater than 1. A unity gain follower, with H=1 (not your circuit), has 1/G*H > 1 for all frequencies up to UGBW which for the UA741 is 0.5 or 1.0MHz.

In your circuit, the H is (R2 + R3) / R3 = 40K/1k = 40. This means, your opamp has no control over output resistance for frequencies higher than $$UGBW * (1/40)$$ or 1.0MHz / 40 == 25KHz.

For your circuit, above 25KHz, the Rout will be 75 ohms. Approximately.

Notice the 1/G*H controls behavior. That factor results from math analyzing the negative feedback. Write out that math